# Why am I getting a high pitched whine in my output?

Tags: audio-recording, audio, mixing

I have the following set up:
Roland Fantom 8 -> Mac via USB & Mixer via 1/4 Mono
Mac -> Mixer via usb to 2x 1/4 cable

When Ableton Live is running, and the Fantom is connected to the mac & the mixer, I get a high pitched whine at approx 8000hz

Am I doing something wrong with having the fantom connected via both?  I need the 1/4 output for typical use, and usb to mac if I want to record.  It is also possible my mixer is super cheap, and that is my problem.